# postgresql Issue when trying to start airflow webserver

Tags: database, postgresql, permissions, airflow, public

I'm running into the following error when attempting to run airflow webserver that I configured to use postgresql:

`ERROR - DB Creation and initialization failed: (psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege) permission denied for schema public
LINE 2: CREATE TABLE ab_permission (
^

[SQL:
CREATE TABLE ab_permission (
id SERIAL NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ab_permission_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT ab_permission_name_uq UNIQUE (name)
)
`
I'm running airflow locally and i'm on a mac.

Any ideas how to fix?

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1.I updated my settings in my airflow.cfg file to the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WsZO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA87Z.png)

2. I ran `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO airflow_user;
3. I restarted the postgresql service.
4. After all this I'm still running into the error.

`

Comment: You didn't grant the create permission on the public schema for user airflow_user

Comment: try the following connection string : postgresql+psycopg2://airflow_user:password@localhost:5432/airflow_db